# Find an element based on attribute in array of jquery objects

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an HTML dom with three divs like this:

```
<div data-tab="1">
</div>
<div data-tab="2">
</div>
<div data-tab="3">
</div>
```

Then I gather all these divs in a jQuery object like this:

```
var $tabs = jQuery( '*[data-tab]' );
```

So now, $tabs contains all three. Thats great. However, I am trying to alter one of them, so I tried using find() to find the object I wanted to alter, but somehow, I cant find any of the objects in $tabs with find().

Example:

```
$tabs.find( '*[data-tab="2"]' ); simply returns []
```

Why isnt this working, or even better, what works? :P

Comment: `.find` only looks at the *descendants* of the selected elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.filter()` function instead of `.find()`:

```
$tabs.filter('[data-tab=2]')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.$tabs = jQuery('*[data-tab]');
var $filteredtabs = $tabs.filter('[data-tab=2]')
console.log($filteredtabs)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-tab="1">
</div>
<div data-tab="2">
</div>
<div data-tab="3">
</div>
```

Demo :  http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/9nxzttjp/